# C++ copy/move constructor and the assignment operator

Tags: c++

I want to know about C++ copy/move constructor and assignment operator, let's first give code example:

**Header:**

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char * name, int age);
    Person(const Person &person);
    Person(Person&&) noexcept;

    virtual ~Person();

    Person &operator=(const Person & other);
    Person &operator=(Person &&other) noexcept;

    char *getName() const;
    int getAge() const;

private:
    char *name;
    int age = 0;
};
```

**Source:**

```
Person::Person() : age(0)
{
    this->name = new char[100];
    memset(this->name, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
}

Person::Person(const char * name, int age) : Person()
{
    std::strcpy(this->name, name);
    this->age = age;
}

Person::Person(const Person &person)
{
    if(this == &person)
    {
        return;
    }
    //delete[](name);
    this->name = new char[100];
    memset(this->name, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
    std::strcpy(name, person.name);
    age = person.age;
}

Person::Person(Person &&other) noexcept
{
    if(this == &other)
    {
        return;
    }
    //delete[](name);
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    other.name = nullptr;
    other.age = 0;
}

Person &Person::operator=(const Person &other)
{
    if(this == &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete[](name);
    name = new char[100];
    memset(name, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
    std::strcpy(name, other.name);
    age = other.age;
    return *this;
}

Person &Person::operator=(Person &&other) noexcept
{
    if(this == &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete[](name);
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    other.name = nullptr;
    other.age = 0;
    return *this;
}

Person::~Person() {
    delete[](name);
    name = nullptr;
}
```

**Now the question is:** Does it really need in the `copy` and `move` constructors that we check for equality if `this==&other`? Because it is a constructor and it is impossible to be equal with other. And also Does it need that in the `copy` and `move` constructors we `delete` (free) the memory? Because the memory has not been allocated yet, then why it needs to be deleted? I say this because I saw in many C++ tutorials that they deleted the memory and check for equality.

**So** if I am right, then the `copy` and `move` constructor can be written like this:

```
Person::Person(const Person &person) : Person()
{
    std::strcpy(name, person.name);
    age = person.age;
}
Person::Person(Person &&other) noexcept
{
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    other.name = nullptr;
    other.age = 0;
}
```

And also how about checking for equality in `move` assignment?

```
Person &Person::operator=(Person &&other) noexcept
```

Thanks!

Comment: Both of these things are normally done only in assignment operators. I can't say I remember ever coming across a learning resource that does either in a constructor.

Comment: It's not likely someone will try to initialize a variable with itself. [But the language itself does allow it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a50729df2b25f7e). Still, I wouldn't bother checking. If people using my code want to self-immolate, it's their prerogative.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can you can tell me why you say that "Still, I wouldn't bother checking"? Here `this` never will be equal to `&other` even with itself-initialize, because `this` is just constructed, but `&other` already constructed. So it is can be meaningless which if do like this `if(this == &other)'.

Comment: `this` **can be equal to** `&other`, it's allowed, just like the code I linked to does (note it's a warning...). But again, I wouldn't bother, because code that is written like that is probably broken in a multitude of ways, it's not your job to stop someone from sabotaging themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know about C++ copy/move constructor and equal operator...

I think you meant the assignment operator `operator=`. The equal operator would be `operator==`.

> Does it really need in the copy and move constructors that we check for equality if this==&other?

No, you don't need this as you already stated.

> Does it need that in the copy and move constructors we delete (free) the memory?

You'll need it in your move- and copy-assignment, because you have to release the old memory to copy (or just set the pointer to) the memory of the other `Person`. Your constructor won't need a delete.

> So if I am right, then the copy and move constructor can be written like this

Yes, these are correct. Are you sure you really want to have fixed 100 bytes for every person?

> And also how about checking for equality in move assignment?

I would not check for equality in move assignment, because move is a very inexpensive operation and it is very unlikely that you are going to assign the same object.

Comment: Nice and clear, thanks! By the way, 100 bytes is just for test purpose. Yes you are right it is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

No, self-initialization check is not needed in constructor. Mainly because it means you are trying to initialize object with uninitialized object, which is a bad idea. Standard library just treats such use as undefined behavior.

Making sure that self-assignment works is something you should do, as it can happen in proper programs. But explicit check is something you should avoid: it forces everyone pay cost for that check, even if it is for something rarely happening. It is better to write your assignment operators to work properly even in case of self-assignment:

```
Person &Person::operator=(Person &&other) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(name, other.name);
    swap(age, other.age);
    return *this;
}
```

It works well in case of self-move assignment — swaps some data with itself. If inlined, it will be likely completely optimised away entirely. In general, destruction of original name is deferred until `other` destruction, but no extra work is done, and there is no perfomance hit. Copy assignment can be written as:

```
Person &Person::operator=(const Person &other)
{
    using std::swap;
    auto new_name = new char[100];
    memset(new_name, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
    std::strcpy(new_name, other.name);
    swap(name, new_name);
    age = other.age;
    delete[](new_name);
    return *this;
}
```

Same operations, no perfomance hit in general case, works in case of self-assignment, easy to make strong exception guarantee, if smart pointers are used instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In assignment operator, if we use `swap()` then in case of self-assignment if the data is so large, then what is the performance penalty if we don't check for the equality? Although you have already mentioned, I want to know does `swap()` ignore the copy process in case of self-assignment?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Swap is usually defined as series of memberwise moves, and moves are fast (you want swap to be fast and noexept). In your case it is pointer and integer swap. Both operations are extremely fast. If compiler detects that self-assignment, it will optimise it to be no-op. Otherwise swaps (and memory allocation in case of copy-assignment) would take place, but why would you care about perfomance of something happening 0.001% of all time? It would be better for self-asssignment to be as fast as all others, instead of fast self-assignment, but everything else is slightly slower.